# How to make estimated value based on amount of text?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make a social media app and the amount of text in a post will differ greatly, so I can't just set the overall estimated height to one number. How would I go about setting the estimated height according to the amount of text in each cell?

Comment: Assuming autolayout is properly displaying your cell, the estimated height is just a best guess.  I wouldn't even remotely worry about improving on your estimate unless you're noticing poor performance and you've collected some amount of evidence suggesting it's entirely related to a frequent and large discrepancy between actual and estimate height of cells.

Comment: @nhgrif Autolayout is working fine. It's just that sometimes it jumps when scrolling.